# Dynamic row add & delete in html table in Blazor web assembly

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a blazor webassembly app where i have this feature to add or delete html row. Can we do it easily in Blazor? or we have to go for javascript? Thanks in advance

I am looking for some output like this or anything similar to my requirement. Any link to such solution also should be helpful. Just the example image:[image: Example image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?
[image]

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Command</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach(var model in models)
  {
  <tr>
    <td>@model.Name</td>
    <td>@model.Value</td>
     <td>
         <button @onclick="() => models.Remove(model)">
             X
         </button>
     </td>
  </tr>
  }

</table>
<button @onclick="@(() => models.Add(new Model(){Name = nameTextField, Value = Int32.Parse(valueTextField)}))">
    New value
</button>
<div>
Name: <input @bind="@nameTextField" @oninput="(e)=> { nameTextField = e.Value ==null? string.Empty:(string)e.Value; }" />
</div>
<div>
Value: <input type="number" @bind="@valueTextField" @oninput="(e)=> { valueTextField = e.Value ==null? string.Empty:(string)e.Value; }" />

</div>
@code {
string nameTextField = "";
string valueTextField = "";
List<Model> models = new()
    {
        new Model(){Name="Row1",Value = 1},
        new Model(){Name="Row2",Value = 2}
    };
}
```

Model.cs:

```cs
public class Model
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Value {get;set;}
    }
```

[Working demo](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QPEKQekS54UWsfd231).

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. But this solution is incomplete for me. How can we add values for the fields ? I mean on Add click a form pops up & those values get added in table .

Comment: Your question is becoming too broad. SO is for sharing proof of concept, not complete solution based on your requirements. But anyway - see the updated answer!

Comment: this helps a lot. I can continue and modify from here. Thanks